# URL не заносится в бд

Tags: url, php, html, sql

Доброго времени суток!

Странные вещи творятся, однако! Есть поле input type text, и при помещении в него строки типа `http://vk.com/id219084397|Виктор Астапов` и последующей отправке формы сервер ругается следующей бранью:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access
> /liter.php on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error
> was encountered while trying to use an
> ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Причем - внимание! - если убрать из строки первый символ - "h" (`ttp://vk.com/id219084397|Виктор Астапов`), то обработка и занесение в БД проходит отлично! Даже не знаю, в чем и дело.

`str_replace http` на, скажем, `_` перед вносом в бд пробовал - все то же...

**Обновление**

Так себя ведет этот код на хостинге, а на локальном сервере (у меня на компе) все опять же работает как по маслу!

Если поиграть с permission у файла liter.php и поставить их на 7 7 7, то ругается он уже так:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal
> error or misconfiguration and was
> unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server
> administrator, webmaster@onclickweb.kz
> and inform them of the time the error
> occurred, and anything you might have
> done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may
> be available in the server error log.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error
> was encountered while trying to use an
> ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Опытным путем понял, что ошибка выдается, не доходя до обработчика. (
Еще опытный путь показал, что сервер ругается только на ссылки Вконтакта.

Comment: Как вариант, заносите в базу ссылки без явного указания протокола:  

`//vk.com/id219084397|Виктор Астапов`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обратиться в тех. поддержку. На shared хостинге вы все равно с настройками ничего не поделаете.

Comment: Да по сему только такой выход и вижу. ( Странно, что пой хостинг так говнится за ссылки на VK, ну, надеюсь, хоть кто-то с подобной проблемой прочитает это и будет уже не так взрывать себе мозг, как я. )

Comment: Жесть, конечно. )) Может, перед отправкой в base64 закодировать, а по получению раскодировать, должно сработать.

Comment: base64 лишнее место будет есть, лучше обрезать не только http_ zj b vk.com, раз все ссылки оттуда... и палиться не будут и экономнее храниться